# Pass data from one API to another using Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am making an API call to return a list of appointments. Each appointment has a clientID as a FK so that we can get client information. Is it possible to get that clientID when I make the call to the appointments API and use the clientID to make a call to a client using ID. Here is what I was thinking of how it might work but it is not working. Also an explanation of why this doesnt work would be nice.

```
export default{
  data (){
      return{
          appointment: [],
          client: []
      }
  },
  created() {
      axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/appointment")
      .then(res => this.appointment= res.data)
      .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
      }),
      axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/client/" + this.appointment.clientID)
      .then(res => this.client = res.data)
      .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
      })
  }
```

Comment: An actual error message or some specifics on what precisely is not working would be helpful. Might be that res.data needs to be processed via JSON.parse in order to make it accessible as intended in your second call. Most likely you are currently binding a plain string (= `res.data`)

Comment: Sorry should’ve added that. When I console log the data it’s returning from the call to the client with ID, it returns null.

Comment: Seems plausible since processing probably already failed before. Check the network tab in your browser to verify that clientID is set correctly in the request to `api/client/`(my guess it is not). Also check what value is actually bound to this.appointment (I guess it is a plain string).

Comment: The client api is working fine I’ve tested it in postman and another page in my app.

Answer (score 2):

It does not work, beacause both axios calls are made simultanisously.

`clientID` is not defined, when you make the second axios call

Make sure the first call is done before using data from that response.

```js
axios.get(...)
.then(response => {
    this.appointment = response.data
    axios.get(".../" + response.data.clientID)
    .then(response => this.client = response.data
})
.catch(e => console.log(e))
```